# Scala inheritance : how to pass a parameter to parameter without declaring it in child?

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance

I would like to initialise a parent object that needs a parameter but without declaring in child constructor

```
class A(name: String)
```

What I see everywhere is

```
class B(name: String) extends A(name)
```

but what I would like to do is

```
class B extends A {
  def this() = this("valueOfName") // string "valueOfName" is passed to A
}
```

Is it possible to do this in Scala?

** EDIT **

This is just a toy example, my real case is more complex, but I want to transform the parameter passed to the parent:

```
class B(other: String) extends A {   
    def this() = this(other ++"valueOfName") 
}
```

Comment: Since B extends A, there is no separate member called "name" in B. There is no B.name that is stored in a different location from A.name. Since B extends A, it has a "name" member that is the one defined in A. So when you want to initialize the "name" differently in instances of B, you are saying that you want to pass different values to the constructor of B. Once you pass a value to the constructor of B, it is assigned to "name". There are no intermediate steps and there is no A.name. You can try this: `class B extends A("specialValue")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the value directly to the constructor of `A`. Like this:

```
class B extends A("valueOfName")
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because this what I asked but this wasn't what I wanted to do, could you look at the edit part please and tell me if you see a solution for that? Thanks

Comment: @samidarko `class B (other: String) extends A (other + "valueOfName")`